# Setting up cron job in a unix server via cpanel

Tags: cron, cpanel, cron-task

I'm actually trying to test running cron jobs in my Unix server (via Cpanel 11)

I've been trying to execute WGET.

My command looks like this :

```
30 11 * * * wget http://www.mydomain.com/myscript.php
```

The server tries to run the job every 5 minutes. But then, I get an error in my email saying

```
/bin/sh: 30: command not found
```

I've tried this also

```
30 11 * * * /usr/lib/wget http://www.mydomain.com/myscript.php
```

No use. I keep getting the same error all the time. 
I use Siteground webhosting provider.

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried googling and finding related posts in Stackoverflow too. No success :(

Comment: Before programming a cronjob, you should check if `wget http://www.mydomain.com/myscript.php` itself is working. It seems to be a code problem, not cronjob.

Comment: Isn't `wget` a unix command? It works on my OS X shell.

Comment: You should put script path relative to the server, not the http:// one. Also, errors should be escaped using `2>/dev/null`.